# How to compare DateTime object that keeps giving 00:00:00 as time to another with no time?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my database, I have DateTime objects that are stored in the format of "M/d/yyyy". They are not strings. 
I am trying to write an SQL query to compare which items are overdue, but when I do Datetime.Today.Date, I get today's date with 00:00:00. Because of the empty time, I cannot compare it to my fields in my database which don't have any. 
Note: my database field is a datetime object and so is Datetime.Today.Date

I have already tried ToString, but I want to keep the column type as a DateTime type.

Comment: wait a second, do you want this in a sql query? or c#?

Comment: SQL Query, sorry.

Comment: All .NET DateTime object contain a Date/Time, whether they are formatted to show one or not. Take both both DateTimes (say d1 and d2) and compare them this way `if (d1.Date == d2.Date) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using MS Access, why not simply use the `Date()` function directly in the SQL query? e.g.:

```
select * from YourTable where YourTable.YourField > Date()
```

Comment: Because the Date() function gives me the Date and the time of 00:00:00. My date objects in my table only have the dates. ex) 8/7/2019. But when I do today.date(), i get 8/7/2019 00:00:00 S AM

Comment: I'm not suggesting `Today.Date()`, but just `Date()` within the SQL query.

Comment: I have done the following: "SELECT Name, Loaners.LaptopID, ExpectedReturnDate FROM Loaners WHERE ExpectedReturnDate > Date()"...
However, it doesnt give me the query I wanted, so i'm assuming it didnt work

Comment: When you say *"It doesn't give me the query I wanted"* what is incorrect about the results? Are certain dates included when they shouldn't be? Are certain dates excluded when they shouldn't be?

Comment: The query was supposed to give me a table where laptops were overdue. However, the results were empty. In my database, I have a return date of 8/5/2019, so that should have shown in the results.

Comment: In that case the SQL should be: `select t.name, t.laptopid, t.expectedreturndate from loaners t where t.expectedreturndate < date()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A C# `DateTime` object has both a date and a time component, and if you don't specify the time component the `Hour`, `Minute`, and `Second` properties will all be set to `0` by default.

When comparing two objects, if you simply do `dt1 == dt2`, it compares both date *and* time, so if they both don't match, it will result in `false`. If you only want to compare the date ignoring time, then use the `DateTime.Date` property.

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2019, 8, 7, 15, 0, 0);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2019, 8, 7);
```

Comparison 1:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt1 == dt2);
```

Result:

> False

Comparison 2:

```
Console.WriteLine(dt1.Date == dt2.Date);
```

Result:

> True